# Position a div dynamically based off the position of an area shape in image

Tags: jquery, imagemap

What is the best way to go about this in jquery if my area shape were to look something like this with this id.

```
 <area id="five" shape="rect" coords="610,22,653,62" href="#" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think an area shape should matter. You can probably just do something like this:

```
var $areaShape = $("#five"), $div = $("<div>Cool Stuff bro.</div>");
$div.css({
  position : "absolute",
  top : $areaShape.offset().top,
  left : $areaShape.offset().left
});
$("body").append($div);
```